# What is the meaning of the small blinking camera symbol in my Canon 70D viewfinder?

Tags: canon, viewfinder, canon-70d

I am using Canon 70d and there is a small camera symbol in my viewfinder. I dont know what that is or what it's showing. When I click the AF button, it starts blinking.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the electronic level indicator. It indicates that you're not holding the camera parallel to the ground but instead have tilted it. The specific configuration indicates that you've got a tilt of greater than 2°.

From page 66 of [the manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/5/0300011965/01/eos70d-im-en.pdf):

[image]

Note that this is configurable — you can turn it off if you don't like it. It's also available on the rear LCD during Live View shooting (where it's maybe a little more obvious as a level).

Also note the manual's warning of a 1° margin of error (or even greater when the camera is far from level).

Answer (score 1):

Its a symbol representing the output of the electronic level. In this instance, the camera is tilted to the left.

See page 66 of the [manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300012004/04/EOS_70D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf)